# Pasting multiple ranges to another sheet in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like the code to paste 'cashb' underneath 'rngcel', but every time 
I run the code 'cashb''s value  appears above 'rngCel'.value. Rngcell's range is from A2:A34, I'd like 'Cashb' to appear right below it at A35.  I tried putting 'A35' in the 
range but it does not work.

This is the code that I want to appear below rngcel.value.

```
Sheets(" Price").Range("A35").Resize(Cashb.Rows.Count).Value = Cashb.Value
```

I'd also like to return the column that's 5 columns  to the right of "cashb"range
I appreciate any help that I receive.

This is the code that I have.Thanks in advance.

```
    Sub liveP()

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rngTicker As Range
    Dim rngCel As Range
    Dim Cashb As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
             ws.Name = "Live"
    Set rngTicker = Worksheets("prices").Range("H16:H200") 
    Set Cashb = Sheets("prices").Range("cashbalances")


    For Each rngCel In rngTicker

        If rngCel.Font.ColorIndex = 33 Then
         Worksheets("Live").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(rngCel.offset(, "-7").Value, rngCel.Value) ' this is range cell value'
         WorkSheets("Live").Range("A35").Resize(Cashb.Rows.Count).Value = Cashb.Value.offset ' this is the value I'd like to appear under rngcel value

            'New data that im posting on the Live sheet'
              Sheets("Live").Range("C2:H33").Formula = "=($B2 +$C5)"
              Sheets("Live").Range("A1") = "Header1"
              Sheets("Live").Range("B1") = "Header2"
              Sheets("Live").Range("C1") = "Header3"
              Sheets("Live").Range("D1") = "Header4"
              Sheets("Live").Range("E1") = "Header5"
              Sheets("Live").Range("F1") = "Header6"

        End If


    Next


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you're doing that in a loop, won't you be overwriting? Also, is cashb a single cell or column? If so `cashb.offset(,5).column` will do the latter.

Comment: You're right I think that is the problem I'm having. Is there an alternative to my solution without looping? I'm fairly new to excel, my solution might be inconsistent.Yes, cashb is a column of 5 rows. Thanks for your help, will try to add the line of code to my solution.

Comment: Why are you looping through `rngTicker`? If the font color index is 33 in more than one cell what should happen? Start with what you are trying to achieve rather than the detail of the code.

Comment: There are multiple cells with the color lightblue. If the cells are light blue its takes that value and pastes them on another sheet 'live' along with another column(column A). Everything in the code works until I try to paste a range underneath rngcel in the 'live" sheet. I received help from another user on the site who advised me to loop.

Comment: But as I say if you hard code A35 you will overwrite each time. Do you want cashb added to the first empty row each time? I'm also confused because at the top you want to add cashb to the prices sheet, but in your code extract you are adding to the live sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try This

```
Sub liveP()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rngTicker As Range
Dim rngCel As Variant 'used in for each this should be variant
Dim Cashb As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long 'dimensioned variable for the last row
Dim CashbRows As Long 'dimensioned variable for Cashb rows
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
         ws.Name = "Live"
Set rngTicker = Worksheets("prices").Range("H16:H200")
Set Cashb = Sheets("prices").Range("cashbalances")
'Assuming "cashbalances" is a named range in the worksheet

CashbRows = Cashb.Rows.Count

For Each rngCel In rngTicker

    If rngCel.Font.ColorIndex = 33 Then
     With Worksheets("Live")
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'set lastrow variable
        .Cells(LastRow, 1) = rngCel.Offset(0, -7).Value 'putting value 7 columns before into live worksheet column A
        .Cells(LastRow, 2) = rngCel.Value 'putting value into live worksheet column B
        .Range(.Cells(35, 1), .Cells(35 + CashbRows, 1)) = Cashb.Offset(, 5).Value 'im not really sure if this line is going to work at all

        'New data that im posting on the Live sheet'
          .Range("C2:H33").Formula = "=($B2 +$C5)"
          .Range("A1") = "Header1"
          .Range("B1") = "Header2"
          .Range("C1") = "Header3"
          .Range("D1") = "Header4"
          .Range("E1") = "Header5"
          .Range("F1") = "Header6"
     End With

    End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

### Modifications:

rngCel is now a variant not a range

Using a LastRow Variable to get away from offset

Removed the array when placing data into "LIVE" because why not

CashbRows will now only be calculated one time before the loop.  Saving time

The `With Worksheets("Live")` statement is a time saving measure.

You were calling A35 as a range, which it is not, then resizing to a range maybe?  Hard to know when I cant tell what "cashbalances" is.  If "cashbalances is only 1 row or may ever be 1 row, then you will need to add an `If Then Else` control to handle it.

Also A35 gets overwritten every single loop...  so not sure what you want to do there.

I hope I was able to understand your questions well enough to get you going in the right direction.

### EDIT

Stop treating "cashbalances" as a named range.  I believe VBA is hanging onto the original row numbers of the range, similar to how Variant arrays start at 1 when assigned as I do in the following.  It does not look like you are modifying "cashbalances" so create a variant array before the loop but after CashbRows.

EXAMPLE:

```
Dim CB() as variant, j as long
with sheets("PUT THE SHEET NAME OR INDEX HERE")
CB = .range(.cells(1,6), .cells(CashbRows,6)).value 'address to whatever .offset(,5) is
'i assumed cashb was in column A
```

Instead of `.Range(.Cells(35, 1), .Cells(35 + CashbRows, 1)) = Cashb.Offset(, 5).Value` Use:

```
For j = 1 to CashbRows
    .cells(34 + j, 1) = CB(j)
Next j
```

Comment: This solution does work. Except I'm getting the same outcome as my other solution.Everything works perfectly, except Cash balances keeps pasting above rngcell. Also, Cashbalances has 5 rows.It doesn't specifically need to be "A35" I just want it underneath rngcell. I'm sorry if I'm not explaining my question well. Heres an image of the desired outcome. https://imgur.com/a/KCK7M    Thank you, I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: `CB = Cashb.Offset(, 5).Value` should work nicely for populating the variant array also.  IDK try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately ,neither solutions  worked for me.I kept getting subscript out of range error on ".Cells(LastRow + j, 1) = CB(j)" . I'm sure if I was a little more experienced I could've debugged it. Thanks, I appreciated your time and effort.

Comment: Heres the code I used . `sheet.Range("Cashbalances").Select
     Selection.Copy
       liveprice.Activate

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
     lastrow2 = Selection.End(xlDown).row

     Range("A1").Select
       Range("A" & lastrow2).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

     End With`